# How can I run a specific vimrc file after running the default one?

Tags: vimrc

How can I run a specific vimrc file after running the default one?

(i.e. run the default one, then one of my choosing)

Answer (score 1):

A vim expert suggested

Use the `-u` and `-S` arguments: `$ vim -u myvimrc.vim -S some_script.vim`; or just `-S`: `$ vim -S some_script.vim`

and that works